# How can we confirm whether the op-amp has -ve feedback?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, ltspice, negative-feedback, closed-loop

Many text books show an op-amp will have negative feedback when o/p is connected back to -ve input through some discretes and under such condition V+=V- is satisfied for op-amp input terminals.

In the below circuit, the simulation results show op-amp is in linear mode of operation (V+=V-).

How do I prove the below circuit has -ve feedback?

1. The red path indicates a potential path from o/p to -ve input terminal. But since V- is permanently tied to GND thru R18- i dont see any -ve feedback action coming into play.
2. The blue path indicates possible -ve feedback action. If output increases, the gate voltage of M2 increases, current increases, R5 voltage becomes more -ve -> eventually bringing the output lower.

Is this analysis correct?

[image]

Comment: I would suspect a mistake or several somewhere in the (very badly drawn) schematic. Lack of feedback being one; potentially dumping 280A through a 55A FET being another. There may be more. Start with your understanding of what that schematic was intended to do...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any kind of feedback in this circuit. Remember in any practical circuit, the power supply nodes (VCC and VSS) are driven by low-impedance sources, so the power supply nodes are not included in any feedback path. The inverting input IN(-) is connected to VSS through R18, so there's no negative feedback. And the non-inverting input IN(+) is connected to VCC through R28 and to VSS through R19, which makes a Thevenin equivalent source. <strike>So the op-amp doesn't even have positive feedback.</strike> There's also a diode in series with the output, which is unusual except for peak detect circuits.

Update: I misread the schematic (thanks @brhans). R19 is in series with R5. Visually I saw the entire lowest level horizontal wire as the VSS supply rail, I didn't notice R5. In spice simulations a value of 10m means 10e-3 or 0.010 ohm, which would be consistent with typical values for a current-sense resistor.

There's also another comment under the question, that seems to indicate I'm not the only person having some trouble following the intention of this design. Let me see if I can redraw it to better express the intention of R5 as a current sensing element. Note that I've placed R5 near the bottom, but slightly higher than the ground/VSS rail level, and I also routed the two sense lines close together on the schematic. When communicating with a PCB layout designer, this kind of detail on the schematic helps alert the PCB designer that these are a differential sense input, that needs to be routed close together.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fff96P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[Rules and guidelines for drawing good schematics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics)

Comment: R19 is not connected to Vss - R5 (probably acting as a current sensor) is in the way.